# ng2: Update value in FirebaseListObservable on keyup

Tags: angular, data-binding, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I'm playing around with Angular2 and Firebase as backend. My goal: Have some input fields which should be synchronized across devices --> 3-way Data-binding.

My approach: `FirebaseListObservable`, `ngFor` in the template and go.

Now, the problem is that every time I hit a key, the whole array/all input fields are re-rendered (that word though! :D), not only the one I'm currently typing in. This makes the cursor pop out of the input so I have to focus it again and the strange behavior restarts.

Am I missing something really general when working with Firebase?
[As the docs state](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgFor-directive.html) in "Change Propagation", only the updated element will be rerendered (which isn't the case obviously).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `*ngFor="let input of item;trackBy:input?.id"`

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgFor-directive.html